# How to go to other view controller when signed in from a google account ? (swift 3) if possible

Tags: swift3, google-signin

I did this: "SecondViewController" is the view controller I want to go to:

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "idSegueContent" {
        secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController //Error is here
    }
}

public func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    if (error) != nil {
        print(error)
    }
    else {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "idSegueContent", sender: self)
    }
}


func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    if let err = error {
        print(error)
    } 

    SecondViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    //Error is here too
}
```

I am trying to login using Gmail account and show the user information in another page when the user is logged in.

Answer (score -1):

You can add this code that will help you navigate to other `ViewController`s:

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!)  {
     if error != nil
    {
        print(error ?? "google error")
        return
    }
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navigation") as! NavigationController

   self.present(newViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)

//  lblUserName.text =  user.profile.email
}
```